# Array In Array in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My javascript code;

```
function callDist(sel)
{
   $.getJSON('Dist.json', function(data){
    var $container = $('#parameters').empty();

    $.each(data.distributions, function(i, distribution){
         $.each(distribution, function(key,value) 
         {
          if(distribution.type==sel.value) {
            alert(distribution.name);
            $.each(distribution.parameters, function(key, value) {
            $container.append(key + ':' + value + '<br />');
            $container.append('<hr />');
          });
         }
    });
 }
 );
 });
 }
```

My Json code;

```
{
"distributions":[
  { 
     "name":"Uniform",
     "type":1,
     "parameters":[{ "minValue":2 , "maxValue":4 }]
  },
  {  "name":"Normal",
     "type":2,
     "parameters":[{ "mean":5 , "standartDeviation":3 }]
  },
  {
     "name":"Exponential",
     "type":3,
     "parameters":[{"lamda":2}]
  },
  {
     "name":"Geometric",
     "type":4,
     "parameters":[{"probability":0.2}]
  }
 ]
}
```

Html code;

```
<select name="selectDistribution" class="span12"  id="Options"       

 onchange="callDist(this);" >
      <option value="0">Choose one distribution</option>
      <option value="1">Uniform</option>
      <option value="2">Normal</option>
      <option value="3">Exponential</option>
      <option value="4" >Geometric</option>
</select>
```

In Json there is an array that created by some distributions.when the user selects some of them from select option I am triggering callDist(sel) function.
When the passed value sel is equal to distribution.type , I want to write the parameters of that distribution to a div.How can I do that?Thanks.

Comment: Never call a variable `JSON`, as that will override the native `JSON` object. And what have you tried to accomplish your task?

Comment: what is `sel.value` supposed to be?

Comment: @MaxArt I changed it but it is still not solved.

Comment: @joeframbach It is passed from a html tag.It is an integer.

Comment: in the first each you have "," extra?

Comment: @ntf Of course. It wasn't a solution to your question, but rather a general suggestion for your coding practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function callDist(sel) {
    $.getJSON('Dist.json', function(json){
        var $container = $('#parameters').empty();


        $.each(json.distributions, function(i, distribution) {
            if(distribution.type==sel.value) {
                $.each(distribution.parameters, function(j, parameters) {
                    $.each(parameters, function(parameter_key, parameter_value) {
                        $container.append(parameter_key + ':' + parameter_value + '<br />');
                        $container.append('<hr />');
                    });
                });
             }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems true but this time, there is no output.

Comment: I run my project from wamp and localhost.And there is no error.Only div tag for paramters is empty now.

Comment: I have it running in a jsfiddle.

Comment: I see the result is correct, but why I cannot get the same result in my project:(

Comment: Have you copy/pasted my solution?

Comment: Ah, I had to modify your json to get the fiddle to work. Replace $.each(distributions...) and the function(distributions) variable names as I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

With `distributions` set up as an array, you'll have to loop through distributions and check to see if the `type` value of each element matches `sel`, and then append the parameters of that object to the div in question, unless position always translates to a certain type. If that's the case, something like

```
var distribution = data[(sel-1)]
```

can be used to set the distribution.

What might make more sense, since there may be cases where position in the array does not correspond to type, is to restructure your JSON so that you have an object instead of an array, like the following:

```
{"distributions":{
    "Uniform":{
        "name":"Uniform",
        "type":1,
         "parameters":[{ "minValue":2 , "maxValue":4 }]
    },
    "Normal":{
         "name":"Normal",
         "type":2,
         "parameters":[{ "mean":5 , "standartDeviation":3 }]
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, I've used the `name` field as the attribute names of the `distributions` object, and can get my parameters for any given distrubution by typing `data[selName].parameters`, in which `selName` is the name corresponding to the selection, but you could just as easily use the type as the attribute name.

Both of these methods would remove the need to loop through the data.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle around it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jagzviruz/P75R8/1/) . I am able to see the alert with the correct value.
I used

```
$('#Options').change()
```

to trigger the function and a few other modifications to work on fiddle.

Comment: I want to get the parameters of the wanted distribution.And I want to write the parameters to parameters div

Answer (score -1):

Remove the 2nd comma in

```
$.each(data.distributions, function(i, distribution,) {
```

Comment: I changed it but this time I got 0:[object Object] at three times.

Comment: but I can get only names of the distributions with your solution.